# jquery make field noneditable, without readonly or disbaled

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, javascript-framework

I am trying to make many of my form field non-editable. 
I can not use disabled as i have to send form data to server even if field is disabled. 
I tried using readonly but I am using jquery datepicker and number of select boxes, which allow user to change the data.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use readonly, but toggle the datepicker function.

Please see this example: http://jsfiddle.net/r9KZP/1/

```
$(function(){
$('#datepicker').datepicker()

$('#disable').click(function(){
     if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
 $('#datepicker').attr('readonly',true)
   .datepicker("destroy");
} else {
 $('#datepicker').attr('readonly',false)
 .datepicker();  
}
});


});
```

and html:

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker">

<input type="checkbox" id="disable"> Disable
```

Hope it will help you.

Best regards